# Data on alcohol usage, addictions, disease in Africa

Tags: data-request, medical, africa

Im looking for an open data set on various alcohol usage statistics for Africa. Preferably the data would be at a subnational/regional or even micro level, such as from surveys. I haven't seen anything from the typical sources such as the world bank though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usaid's demographic and health surveys collect alcohol consumption in some surveys.  you could start working with the microdata here

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/demographic%20and%20health%20surveys%20%28dhs%29

Answer (score 1):

The Data on Alcohol and Tobacco in Africa (DATA) research unit based at the University of Cape Town makes its microlevel data (such as from surveys) available.

To access this data you can use the following link: https://www.datafirst.uct.ac.za/dataportal/index.php/catalog/DATA/about

This link takes you to DataFirst, an Open Data portal belonging to the University of Cape Town.